# How to tell clients what name dows file have when downloading using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, web, spring-boot, wget

We are implementing web-app and there is a problem with download file link.
The code of controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file" , method = RequestMethod.GET,
produces = "application/jar")
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> getFile() {
    FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(new File(PATH_TO_FILE));
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FILE_NAME);
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/jar");
    ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(resource, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

Problem is that it downloads well from browser, but not, for instance, from wget.

when I try to make

```
wget localhost:8080/file
```

I download it but not as file.jar (which is FILE_NAME), but just a file without extension.

Is there any solutions?

UPD: I've also tried to change request to **file.jar**. But by some reason this request didnt shoot. Also I tried to make a regexp (i dont remember well, something like this)

```
{filename:[a-zA-Z0-9]+}{extension:\\.[a-z]+}
```

But it only cought requests like aaa.bbb, fsdf.sdkfjsdkf (I mean some random), but not a file.jar. Seems like there is special request handlers in Spring Boot?

Nevertheless, how to solve such problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to modify your solution to be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download/{fileName}" , method = RequestMethod.GET,
produces = "application/jar")
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> getFile(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {
    File pathToFile = findPathToFile(fileName);
    FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(new File(pathToFile));

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/jar");
    ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(resource, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

Then you can call using wget:

```
wget localhost:8080/download/file.jar
```

Another option if you want to compromise with your wget command, you can use -O flag:

```
wget -O file.jar localhost:8080/file
```

Comment: Didn't work :(
I tried it also. The problem is that, by some reason, "/download/file.jar" isn't cought by request mapped value "/download/{fileName}"

Comment: The funniest thing is that request for "file.jara" is caught, but not a "file.jar"  Seems like there is kind of special request mapping

Comment: Can you try using this expression value = "/download/{fileName:.+}"

Comment: it produces the same result: if I request for download/file.extension, then I get it. But if for file.jar - I get nothing